# Prevent an object from being coppied in C# PowerPoint 2010 add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in, powerpoint

I am building a PowerPoint 2010 C# add-in using Visual Studio 2010. One of the functions of the add-in is to add a shape to the current slide. Once the shape is added to the slide though, I need to prevent it from being copied. That is where I am running into issues. I have looked at all the application level events and am not seeing any sort of beforeCopy or beforePaste type of events.

The only option I can think of right now is to add a keydown event listener to listen for "ctrl+c" and block that if my shape is selected and then create a custom right click menu (not even sure if I can yet) to remove the "Copy" option if my shape is selected. There has to be simpler option though.

Anyone have any ideas how I would prevent a user from copying a shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands executed by built-in ribbon buttons Microsoft Office can be disabled or re-routed. Microsoft calls this "Repurposing", an introduction can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

So another approach could be to "repurpose" the built-in Copy button with something like this. (Needs to be returned by GetCustomUI to customize the ribbon, see the link above.) This modifies the action executed by the Copy button and the callback method that determines whether the button is enabled or not.

```
<command idMso="Copy" onAction="copyAction" getEnabled="copyEnabled" />
```

Implement `copyAction` to return `cancelDefault = true` when your shape is selected so it will not be copied.

Implement `copyEnabled` to return `false` if your shape is selected. Remember to invalidate the button on selection change events.

Actually, one of both approaches should be sufficient. I guess `onAction` is easier to implement.

Comment: Very new to building add-ins so I am sure I am just confused. What ribbon copy button are you referring to? I do not have a copy button on my ribbon bar.

Comment: I was talking about the built-in Copy button and just tried to make the answer clearer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I will see if I can implement tomorrow as it does seem a lot simpler. If it works out I will change the correct answer to you. Thanks.

Comment: So I decided not to implement your solution because I will still have to loop through every object that is selected or every slide if multiple slides are selected to see if it is selected, then cancelDefault. That is what I am already doing essentially except for the overhead of letting it copy then deleting it. It isn't broke so I am not going to fix it. However, If I had to rewrite it or if it was an enterprise solution I would for sure use yours instead of mine. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Fair point, never change a running system :). Thinking about it some more I realized my approach won't prevent that the user copies a shape by dragging + Ctrl key. So you probably would need to listen to the SelectionChanged event anyway for a fool-proof solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the loop on this, I am sharing my work-around in the hopes that someone else who has this issue will not waste as much time as I have on this. I ended up just using the *SlideSelectionChanged* and *WindowSelectionChange* events and a dictionary to delete my objects that have been coppied.

First, when my shape is added to the stage I add a new entry into the dictionary containing the shape name (in my case it was actually a group of shapes) and its ID.

```
itemIDDictionary.Add(myGroup.Name, myGroup.Id);
```

*WindowSelectionChange* is a fairly simple check. It just looks to see if the newly selected item is in the dictionary already. If it is, it then checks to see if the ID matches. If not, it deletes the item. This works because when you copy and paste an item, the newly pasted item is automatically selected on the slide.

```
public void itemSelectionChange(PowerPoint.Selection SelectedItem)
{
    try
    {
        if (Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon2.itemIDDictionary.ContainsKey(SelectedItem.ShapeRange.Name))
        {
            for (int shapeIDCount = 0; shapeIDCount < Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon2.itemIDDictionary.Count; shapeIDCount++)
            {
                if (!Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon2.itemIDDictionary.ContainsValue(SelectedItem.ShapeRange[1].Id))
                {
                    SelectedItem.Delete();
                    MessageBox.Show("You can not copy the browser object.\nAdd a new one using the ribbon bar");
                }
            }
        }
    }
catch {}
```

*SlideSelectionChanged* is just a little bit more complicated as I have to loop through all the shapes on the slide.

```
try
{
    if (SldRange.Count > 0)
    {
        var showWarning = false;
        for (int slideCount = 1; slideCount <= SldRange.Count; slideCount++)
        {
            int shapeCount = 1;
            while (shapeCount <= SldRange[slideCount].Shapes.Count)
            {
                if (Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon2.itemIDDictionary.ContainsKey(SldRange[slideCount].Shapes[shapeCount].Name))
                {
                    if (!Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon2.itemIDDictionary.ContainsValue(SldRange[slideCount].Shapes[shapeCount].Id))
                    {
                        SldRange[slideCount].Shapes[shapeCount].Delete();
                        showWarning = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        shapeCount++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    shapeCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(showWarning == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You can not copy the browser object.\nAdd a new one using the ribbon bar");
        }
    }
}
catch { }
```

As I said in my initial post, I am sure there is a cleaner way to do this. I just couldn't find one to save my life.